# How to access data from Hyper Terminal using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, gsm, hyperterminal

Hi I have a GSM modem through which i am sending a SMS which comes in Hyper Terminal.

What i want is...for Click Event of button1...
When i click on the button. It runs an `AT Read command` (say 'CTRM RD<1>') in hyper terminal and the message which is being received suppose **"Hello Hi"** *in hyper terminal is fetched and shown in a text box in form.*

Please suggest any code ?

or sample ?

*Also is this technology (hyper terminal and all) is available in **Windows Azure** ? Mean can we implement same logic in Cloud also ?*

Thanks

Comment: take a look at @benJima answer - it is great suggestion ! Also you can look into [this (gsm modem)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem) or [this non-gsm modem](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21496/RS232-Modem-Wrapper)  communication from C# examples.